# How to get all enumerable properties of a specific type from a class

Tags: c#, reflection

Lets say I have a poco class that looks like this:

```
public MyClass
{
    public IAssimilator p1 {get; set;}
    public IAssimilator p2 {get; set;}
    public IAssimilator p3 {get; set;}
    public string n1 {get; set;}

    public List<IAssimilator> p4 {get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<IAssimilator> p5 {get; set;}
    public List<int> n2 {get; set;}
}
```

I have a method elsewhere that returns a `List` of all properties on MyClass that have type of `IAssimilator`. It looks like this:

```
private List<IAssimilator> GetAssimilatorsOnClass(MyClass myInstance)
{
    return typeof(MyClass).GetProperties()
                .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(IAssimilator))
                .Select(p => p.GetValue(myInstance) as IAssimilator)
                .ToList();
}
```

It will return a `List<IAssimilator>` that contains the values of p1 thru p3.

What I would like to add is something to also get IAssimilator values inside any enumerable property. In this case, it should return a List that contains the values in p4 and p5, but not n2. I don't really know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to filter for all properties haveing a type which is `IEnumerable<IAssimilator>` or derived from `IEnumerable<IAssimilator>`. You can do this simimar to what you already did:

```
private IEnumerable<IEnumerable<IAssimilator>> GetAssimilatorListsOnClass(MyClass myInstance)
{
    typeof(MyClass)
        .GetProperties()
        .Where(p => typeof(IEnumerable<IAssimilator>).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType))
        .Select(p => p.GetValue(myInstance))
        .Cast<IEnumerable<IAssimilator>>();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This gives me a place to start. I’ll play around with your suggestion and I’ll be right back!